# Opcion "abrir con" para un video con flutter

Tags: flutter

Desde hace mucho tengo esta pregunta. Quería saber si en flutter se puede tener un video, en este caso una url, en el cual con un boton se pueda abrir ese menu de "abrir con" para verlo en un reproductor del celular.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola!!! Disculpa, es que soy muy nuevo en esto.
Lo que quisiera saber es que si tengo un video:

https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/012/979/original/record_player_011.mp4

He visto que en algunas apps para ver un video da la opción de poder verlo en el reproductor del movil (interno).

Por ejemplo, tener un boton que abra ese menu(abrir con) para poder elegir el reproductor con el cual poder ver el video.

No se si me expliqué bien y si es posible o no, pero le doy las gracias por la atención igualmente, buen dia/noche!!!